# How to correctly remove a vue-select multiselect item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue-select multiselect (http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/) defined as

```
<v-Select label="label" multiple :on-change="updateCities" :options="cities"></v-Select>
```

The method updateCities is defined as

```
'updateCities': function (menuItem) {
            var name = ''
            // iterate thru the elements in the multiselect
            menuItem.forEach(function (elem, i) {
                name = elem.label
                return name
            })
            // push the selected element to an array in the data model
            this.state.city.push(name)
        }
```

and the data model is defined as

```
'data' () {
        return {
            'state': {
                'city': []
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on the multiselect and choose a city, both the menu and the data model array `city` is updated correctly but when I click on the X on the top right of the menu item to remove the element from menu and from the data model array `city`. as shown below
[image]

The element is correctly removed from the menu but not from the data model array `city`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you put together a fiddle/codepen demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Should you be clearing `this.state.city` before you push to it? I can't tell. Note that a `return` in a `forEach` is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by assigning the value of this.state.city to the menu item as:

```
'updateAdvertisers': function (menuItem) {
            this.state.city= menuItem.map(elem => elem.label)
        }
```